run doctl as jenkins user
We have a Jenkins CI server, running on Ubuntu. I can login as root, but jenkins user is running the pipelines. As part of a pipeline, I would like to push images to digital ocean registries.
I can successfully authenticate, login and push if I'm acting as root user, but I cannot make it work as jenkins user (as part of the pipeline). If I call sudo -u jenkins doctl auth init for example, it wants to write to /root/.config file, which is not allowed because of permission issues of course.
Somehow I want to be able to run doctl connected to jenkins user and not to root user. Either installing doctl command it to jenkins user or force using config files/folder of user jenkins.
(As it probably turned out to you, I'm not a linux expert.)

You don't need sudo -u jenkins - your Jenkins is already running as user jenkins. Just normal
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'DO_API_TOKEN', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
  sh script: '''
    doctl auth init --access-token "$TOKEN"
  '''
}

Obviously you need to add DO_API_TOKEN to your Jenkins credentials as a "Secret text" first.
